# Find a Excel file in directory, compress and send it to another folder

Tags: python, excel, automation, directory, path

I have an Excel file WK6 that is downloaded in the below folder:

```
C:\Users\kj\Scripts\Sh\Result\Wk6
```

The Python script should first navigate till the above directory and then find the excel file WK6 (the name of the excel file changes as per week) and compress it. Then move it to some other directory.

Please help me understand how can I find and compress the file in python?

Comment: You say you're looking for an Excel file named `WK6` in a folder named `Wk6`, but that its name changes every week? Sorry, that doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for zipping the file you can use following:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os

path = r'C:\Users\kj\Scripts\Sh\Result\Wk6'
os.chdir(path)
ZipFile('<new path>/name.zip', 'w').write('Wk6.csv')
```